# References and Modules in Typescript

Tags: javascript, modularity, typescript1.4

I am building a project in Typescript. I have a file xyz.ts which has a Module defined as X Where I have a class a.
Similarly I have another class abc.ts also under the Module x, having class b.

```
//file xyz.ts
module X {
'use strict';
export class a{
}

//File abc.ts
module X {
'use strict';

export var appData: any;
export class b{
}
```

If I try to access appData from xyz.ts, it doesn't. However in compiled JS(gained by commenting the code which is trying to access the file, and then manually uncomment the line in generated js) it works fine.

What would be the appropriate route to access and build in this scenario ?
Also, Would I be able to access files having same module, but separated by projects ? (two different Typescript project, both having same Module)
[Though that would be illogical]

Comment: Also, On similar lines, Adding a reference to a file works fine, but that adds referenced files to generated output. Is there a way to get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use appData from xyz.ts, you will need to import it:

```
// xyz.ts
import abc = require("./abc")
var myAppData = abc.X.appData;
```

Hope this helps.